# Displaying an image on desktop with transparent background window in python 2.7

Tags: python, widget

I'm trying to draw an image on the screen without a window behind it(alpha included).

I'm using python 2.7 on windows 7 and have checked every graphical library I could find and have tried researching it over and over. Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i am not sure if this works but you can try it and update me about it

http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/384